# ReactJS, Checkbox doesn't

Tags: reactjs, redux

I Have a ReactJS checkbox component. When `onChange` is called I can log the new state and see it changing, but it never actually re-renders the checkbox into the new state. So the `ADD_ID` action is never called. See code below:

```
  class CheckBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        checked: true
      }
    }

    changing = (e) => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({checked: !prevState.checked}), () => {
        console.log(this.state.checked); // false
        this.state.checked
          ? store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ID', id: this.props.id })
          : store.dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_ID', id: this.props.id });
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <label>
          Include
          <input onChange={this.changing} checked={this.state.checked} type='checkbox'/>
        </label>
      )
    }
  }
```

Is there a lifecycle hook that I have to call? I was under the impression that the component would re-render when either it's props or state changes, in this case, as shown by the `console.log(this.state.checked)`, the state has changed, but the component doesn't re-render.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with above code. There should be something else that might cause you a trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The `event` has already a `checked` property for you. You're doing it in a way that's a bit weird.

Change your function to something like:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
      const isChecked = e.target.checked
      if(isChecked){
        store.dispatch({type:'ADD_ID', id:this.props.id})
      } else {
        store.dispatch({type:'REMOVE_ID', id:this.props.id})
      }
      this.setState(checked: isChecked)
    }
```

It's however still strange that you're using at the same time internal state and Redux. You may want to rethink your approach here.

React docs on forms, which I recommend you to read in 5 min:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html